# Left side navigation tablet/mobile app

Tags: navigation

I have a task to build app for elderly people(Users). I work in a med tech company therefore my users are often very sick.

App will be distributed on our own tablet devices and there will be limited use of smartphones.

This is the blockout of the app. Red is content. Navigation is at the bottom. Top bar is above the white line on top. As You can see there is the green color on sides, It is basically free/unused space.[image]

Because I wanted to use free space to get my content little bit bigger(Bigger fonts and icons) I wanted to eliminate free space/green space.

For that I moved navigation from bottom to the left. Like this.

[image]

This allowed me to increase the size of the content.

My question is: Do you have experiences with left navigations on tablet in terms of UX. Is this something that can work or should I avoid it? What are your thoughts guys ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Left or right navigation at tablets are perfect, **lowering a bit to the bottom**.

Think about **ergonomics**.

[image]

[image]

You should read tis articles about physiology of the ipad.

https://uxplanet.org/how-to-make-user-friendly-application-ipad-physiology-b1b6b65a3374

This are the all position safe placement of important action reducing all the interaction costs between position.

[image]

Comment: This is such a great post @Juan Thanks a lot for this. I will leave it open for few days maybe some ppl have more stuff to say.

Comment: Sure trixo, no problem.